# Windows 11 jumplist is extremely slow

Tags: performance, windows-11, taskbar, jumplist, windows-11-v22h2

My jumplist for all the programs pinned on my taskbar is extremely slow. I'm running a new Windows 11 22H2 laptop.

All Office app and also other apps are affected.

I tried deactivating the flag in Settings > Personalization > Start > Turn On the switch against Show recently opened items in Start, Jump Lists, and File Explorer. This way the jumplist is fast but of course empty. As soon as I reactivate the flag, the jumplist is slow again.

I use the jumplist a lot both for pinned items and history. For now I first activated the flag, pinned the documents and deactivated the flag. Of course now I have only pinned items and I lost history. But even this workaround is a pain because in Windows 11 I'm not allowed to drag files to the app on the bar so I have no way to pin documents but to enable the history temporary.

I searched on several topics and could not find the same exact problem.